# c# Insert,Delete, and Edit in Same form load datagridview

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview

I have a datagridview with 4 columns.  1 of which is a manually added deletecheckbox column (The first column).  There's some strange behavior when I try and delete multiple rows based on the checked value.  For example, if I check 2 rows, 1 gets deleted.  If I check 5 rows, 3 gets deleted. So basically half of what I click gets deleted. The ones don't get deleted are remained checked, and I would have to click the update button again to remove more.  If I want to delete ALL checked checkboxes with one button click, what do I need to fix?

Entire Button Click Event:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlCommand cmdAdd = new SqlCommand("insert into Josh_REL_Table (UserID, RoleName) Values (@UserID,@RoleName)", con);
        SqlCommand cmdEdit = new SqlCommand("update Josh_Rel_Table SET UserID = @UserId, RoleName=@RoleName where RelationID=@RelationID", con);
        con.Open();


        cmdAdd.Parameters.Add("@UserID", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        cmdAdd.Parameters.Add("@RoleName", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        cmdAdd.Parameters.Add("@RelationID", SqlDbType.VarChar);

        cmdEdit.Parameters.Add("@UserID", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        cmdEdit.Parameters.Add("@RoleName", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        cmdEdit.Parameters.Add("@RelationID", SqlDbType.VarChar);

        if (DGV1.RowCount >= 1)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < DGV1.RowCount - 1; x++)
            {
                if (DGV1.Rows[x].Cells[1].Value.ToString() == "" || DGV1.Rows[x].Cells[1].Value == null)
                {
                    cmdAdd.Parameters["@UserID"].Value = DGV1.Rows[x].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
                    cmdAdd.Parameters["@RoleName"].Value = comboBox1.Text;
                    cmdAdd.Parameters["@RelationID"].Value = DGV1.Rows[x].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                    cmdAdd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                if (!DGV1.Rows[x].IsNewRow)
                {
                    cmdEdit.Parameters["@UserID"].Value = DGV1.Rows[x].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
                    cmdEdit.Parameters["@RoleName"].Value = comboBox1.Text;
                    cmdEdit.Parameters["@RelationID"].Value = DGV1.Rows[x].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                    cmdEdit.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                if (Convert.ToBoolean(DGV1.Rows[x].Cells[0].Value))
                {
                     List<DataGridViewRow> selectedRows = (from newRow in DGV1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>() where Convert.ToBoolean(newRow.Cells["Delete"].Value) == true select newRow).ToList();
                    if (MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Do you want to delete {0} rows?", selectedRows.Count), "Confirmation", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
                    {
                        foreach (DataGridViewRow newRow in selectedRows)
                        {

                                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM Josh_REL_Table WHERE RelationID = @RelationID", con))
                                {
                                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RelationID", newRow.Cells["RelationID"].Value);

                                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                                    DGV1.Rows.Remove(newRow);
                                }

                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        }


            MessageBox.Show("Record updated!");
            con.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should delete the rows backwards, beginning with the last row working your way through to the first, because otherwise the index is wrong. Consider you want to delete the rows with index 2 and 4:

```
index  actual row
1      Row 1
2      Row 2 <-- If you delete this
3      Row 3
4      Row 4
5      Row 5
```

This basically means that after deleting the row with index 2 you will continue on the row with index 3 which is now Row 4 so you never handled what should happen to Row 3:

After deletion you land here

```
index  actual row
1      Row 1
2      Row 3
3      Row 4
4      Row 5
```

Just change your loop to:

```
for (int x = DGV1.RowCount - 1; x >= 0; ; x--)
```

---

The part for the expression:

Everywhere you assume you van have a cell value that you want to convert to a string but might be null needs to be escaped, otherwise you will receive an error:

```
// Old
cmdEdit.Parameters["@UserID"].Value = DGV1.Rows[x].Cells[2].Value.ToString();

// New
cmdEdit.Parameters["@UserID"].Value = (DGV1.Rows[x].Cells[2].Value != null) ? DGV1.Rows[x].Cells[2].Value.ToString() : "";
```

The part below new evaluates the expression and converts the value to string if it is not null or sets the value to "" if it is null.

Kind of like this:

```
variable = (Expression) ? (will be evaluated if true) : (will be evaluated if false)
```

Comment: Thank you.  However, when I re-run it I get an error "object reference not set to an instance of an object" on line " if (DGV1.Rows[x].Cells[1].Value.ToString() == "" || DGV1.Rows[x].Cells[1].Value == null)"                           Even though I'm looping the other way, the data is the same so why am I getting this?

Comment: Can you move the test for null to the left of th OR? Then it is first tested for NULL and if it is not NULL the other condition is tested (empty string). Null cannot be converted to string and so it will throw an error. Try this: if (DGV1.Rows[x].Cells[1].Value == null || DGV1.Rows[x].Cells[1].Value.ToString() == "")"

Comment: When I debug, it looks in the if statement now, but that first line causes that same error. ( cmdAdd.Parameters["@UserID"].Value = DGV1.Rows[x].Cells[2].Value.ToString();)

Comment: The row where this happens might have empty fields. Can you check the value of "x" when the error occurs and check the value that should be converted? My best quess is that you have a new no value for that cell. This in turn means the value is Null, which again cannot be converted to string.

Comment: Right, My goal is to just add rows to the datagridview/database just by filling out the rows, edit the rows by just replacing the values, and delete rows based on checkboxes.  When the form and datagridview loads, the last line shows n unchecked checkbox and an empty cell under "userID" to fill in.

Comment: Oh, and the value of x is 18.

Comment: Sorry, mispoke.  The error occurs on the if statement line, not inside it.

Comment: Even though you first tested for the value to be null by moving that condition to the left of the OR operator || ?

Comment: Yes, I switched the line positioning of the if statements to see if that made a difference, but yeah I took your advise.  It's back to having the error on the if statement.  I showed the changes above in my question.

Comment: Sorry, it's cell[2] you are trying to ceonvert. Try to add the conditional statement to the right of your equation instead of just the...tostring()

Comment: Will have to dirve home now but send you the statement later.

Comment: I extended my answer for the part about the error when trying to convert null to string. This can occur in addCmd and in the editCmd part. Basically everywhere you try to convert a value of null to string.

Comment: I ended up doing my delete a bit different.  I edited the code above.  This works great!  The minor bug is....if in the form I do an add AND delete on one form load.....  say I delete 5 records and add 5 new records, the delete works right, and the "add" adds all but the the first checked item, which is the last checked in the loop since it's backwards.

Comment: Oh wait, I didn't reverse my loop back...will that make a difference?

Comment: Actually my solution was to make 3 seperate for loop statements with an if statement

Comment: Great, most importantly you found a solution. When working with lists (including deletion) you should always go from the last entry to the first, because of the index problem.